# If Git finds merge conflict, how can i fix that in revision control?

Tags: git

i always work with branches. But sometimes, a particular changeset is in conflict with an another branch's changeset.

- Changeset 1  added new code
- changeset 2 from branch 2 is based on the old code. (more changeset in branch 2)

When I pull in changeset 2 it complains about conflict with changeset 1 which is already on master.

How can I fix changeset 2 such that when we accept PR or git rebase locally we don't have to go through manual fix?

```
git checkout commit-hash
fix commit
git commit
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

now what? i have already pushed previous changes to my repo and there are many more changesets in the original branch (branch 2)

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you could use rebasing, as described in [this section of the Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: maybe it is duplicate. maybe not. see my edit please. I am basically stuck what to do after rebase.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question with a visual (`git log --graph --all -20`) description of the current state of your repository so that we have a better idea of exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question properly, but it looks like you want to rebase your branch 2 to either master or branch 1, before merging it into master.